# Repairing a Partition that doesn't show up in Disk Utility

Tags: partition

I have a friend's flash drive that has been acting very strange. I am able to get the Sandisk factory partition that is 64 MB to show up, but not the actual 8GB partition with all of his files. Nothing has been intentionally formatted.

Anything I can do in Disk Utility to solve this issue?

Thanks for your help!

Scott

Answer (score 1):

If you run following in Terminal

```
defaults write com.apple.DiskUtility DUDebugMenuEnabled 1
```

That will enable new tab in Disk utility called debug.

In that tab you can now select to show all partitions (including the hidden ones)